# How can I use the Jmeter __Random(Date) functions with a Seed?

Tags: jmeter

Is it any way I can use a seed with Jmeters __randomDate and the other __random functions? Need to repeatedly generate the same random dates and other random values for a testplan.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can store the generated date into a variable by providing the variable name as the 3rd parameter of the [__RandomDate()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomDate) function:

[image]

Alternatively you can use [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) to generate a random date using "normal" Java SDK [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class, if you need help with this provide desired dates range and output format.

Comment: Sorry for confusion - my question was about using a seed together with the Jmeter random functions so I can replay a test run using the same random dates. IIU your answer correct I have to use Java random functions to do that?